# "Its" or "It's" user interface is primitive

Tags: grammar, apostrophe

When referring to a system. Which of the following is correct?

> It's user interface is primitive

or

> Its user interface is primitive

The reason I'm confused is because I was taught that in this situation apostrophe "s" means "is" or "has". You cannot therefore say "it is user interface is primitive" or "it has user interface is primitive". Can it however be argued that the user interface belongs to the system and therefore the apostrophe is required?

Comment: Actually your last sentence is further argument for why it should be "Its"; no apostrophe indicates the possessive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"It's" is an abbreviation or contraction of "it is". You use it in the same way as you use "you're" instead of "you are". It has no other meaning. "Its" is a possessive pronoun and used in the same way as his, hers, theirs, ours and yours. It indicates ownership.